# Android Bluetooth Printer Connection error

Tags: java, android

I am trying to print some text to Bluetooth printer.But when checking "(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)" this code always it's true. That means permission can't get. Please help me to solve this

My code is

Android Manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
```

connection code

```
 void openBT() throws IOException {
        // Standard SerialPortService ID
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

            return;
        }
        mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
        mmSocket.connect();
        mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
        mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();

        beginListenForData();
        sendData();
       /* Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth Opened",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
    }
```